# Linux / Unix selecting specific data in same row

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep

I've tried to do this by my self using grep, awk, search and many other commands i found on Google but it didn't worked out.

For example, i have test.txt that contains:

```
aaa, bbb, 333, 222,
ccc, kkk, 222, eee,
333, ooo, qqq, 555,
333, iii, uuu, 222,
```

and what i need to do, to select rows, that has 222 and 333 in a same row.
So i should get :

```
aaa, bbb, 333, 222,
333, iii, uuu, 222,
```

What I tried so far is :

```
$ egrep -R -w '222|333' test.txt     
$ awk '/222|333/' failas
```

also I know how to find rows, which is not having 222 or 333

```
$ grep -v -e "222" -e "333"
```

But as i said, I still can't find command to find that specific data, in a same row.

Thanks for help.

Comment: `grep 222 | grep 333` should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry but no, it still selects 222 and 333 all over the test.txt file, not only those in a same row..

Edit : my bad, it selected only 333 all over test.txt file

Answer (score 3):

I'd use awk.

```
$ awk '/222/ && /333/' file
aaa, bbb, 333, 222,
333, iii, uuu, 222,
```

OR

```
$ grep -P '^(?=.*\b222\b)(?=.*\b333\b)' file
aaa, bbb, 333, 222,
333, iii, uuu, 222,
```

Comment: @TomasŠiaudvytis remember you can accept an answer if your problem is solved. Do it by checking the tick mark below the vote count.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU grep:

```
grep 222, file | grep 333,
```

or

```
grep '222,.*333,\|333,.*222,' file
```

or

```
grep -e '222,.*333,' -e '333,.*222,' file
```

Output:

```
aaa, bbb, 333, 222,
333, iii, uuu, 222,
```

Comment: Wow, really great website, and the command works.

Thanks for help.

Comment: @TomasŠiaudvytis remember you can accept an answer if your problem is solved. Do it by checking the tick mark below the vote count.